# Not sure what this line does

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(or (parse-integer (prompt-read "Rating") :junk-allowed t) 0)
```

This line confuses me quite a bit. the full program is here if you need it to follow: http://paste.lisp.org/display/124929

'Parse-integer' will turn a string into and integer right? if possible. And ':junk-allowed t' makes it accept junk strings somehow right?

Not sure what the 'or' and the 0 at the end are though.

Thanks.

Comment: You can find answers to all your questions in [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/) or [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/)

Answer (score 5):

`or` goes through the forms passed to it, evaluates them in order until it finds one that does not evaluate to nil, and returns that result. So this will return the result of `parse-integer` if that call succeeds in parsing an integer, or 0 if not.

Comment: so if i enter 7 in the prompt, thats non-nil so the line ends, but if i typed some garbage like 'seven' it would return 0?

Comment: The `:allow-junk t` means that a string like "11eleventy!" parses as the number 11, with PARSE-INTEGER returning the values 11 and (IIRC) 2 (the position after where it last saw a valid 'numerical symbol'; what constitutes valid numerical symbols depends on the radix you want to read in).